# Collapse/Combine Rows with some summation on the remaining column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe which has three columns -> Date, x, y.
In that dataframe there are multiple rows with same date value but even for the same dates the values of x & y are different. I want to combine all the dates and make it unique and in the place of 'x' & 'y' I want the summation. I apologise I am new to python, I might be asking a noob question here.

Input:
df-->

```
Date          X    Y
2019-01-01    1    1
2019-01-01    0    1
2019-01-01    0    0
2019-01-01    1    1
2019-01-01    0    1
2019-01-02    1    0
2019-01-02    1    1
2019-01-02    0    1
2019-01-03    0    1
2019-01-03    1    1
2019-01-04    1    0
```

Expected Output:

```
Date          X    Y
2019-01-01    2    4
2019-01-02    2    2
2019-01-03    1    2
2019-01-04    1    0
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Date').sum()`

Comment: Wow! It was that simple.

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks a lot brother for quick response.

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help